# Why jQuery UI 1.10 remove jquery dialog zIndex option?

Tags: jquery, dialog, z-index

I found the latest version of jQuery UI(1.10) remove the `zIndex` option. And it's confirmed on the jQuery website.

It really shocked me. Please think about this:

When we have an jqgrid, and use `editrow()` or `addrow()` to open a edit dialog to edit something, and there are many fields inside, some of which have self-defined event, such as, when you click it, it will show another jQuery dialog to show some treeview items to chose.

Under jQuery UI 1.9 (included), you can set the jQuery dialog's `zIndex` option to bigger than the jqgrid edit dialog's (jqgrid edit dialog support set `zIndex`), so the jQuery dialog always be upon and could be seen and used.

Under jQuery UI 1.10, you cant set `zIndex`, so the jQuery dialog is always behind the jqgrid edit dialog.

I think such scene is very common.

Why jQuery UI 1.10 remove jQuery dialog `zIndex` option? How to control the `z-index` order when there is more than one dialog?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think I understand your problem. The CSS z-index for the jQuery UI dialog is not high enough to always show above your content. Here's a quick fix:

```
/* A class used by the jQuery UI CSS framework for their dialogs. */
.ui-front {
    z-index:1000000 !important; /* The default is 100. !important overrides the default. */
}
```

Comment: thank you, I think this will be fix it. But I wish jquery dialog not remove the zIndex option.

Comment: jQuery UI is open source, so you _can_ influence what's in there and what now. If you have valid reasons they will probably listen to you. You can get startet here: http://contribute.jquery.org/open-source/

Comment: Didn't work for me.  But this did... .ui-dialog {
    z-index:999 !important; 
}

Comment: See this page for a good explanation of the new stacking paradigm: http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/stacking-elements/

Answer (score 6):

Just read the change-log from [jQuery UI 1.10](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#removed-zindex-option) (together with [the bug](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8729) that has been filed for it):

> **Removed zIndex option**
>
> Similar to the stack option, the zIndex option is unnecessary with a proper stacking implementation. The
> z-index is defined in CSS and stacking is now controlled by ensuring
> the focused dialog is the last "stacking" element in its parent.

In other words: You should property stack the elements instead of "hacking" your way to stacking using the zIndex option.

Comment: But use the option zIndex is a very simple way to control the z-order, I don't think it's a "hacking way". How to stack the element property? The focused dialog is not always the last stacking element in its parent when there are a lot object.

Comment: MarcoK, do you mean the jquery UI 1.10 will make the focused dialog be stacking on the top automatically? I found it's not. Or what I need to do to make it stacking to the top?

Comment: Does anyone have an example of a "proper stacking implementation" using absolutely positioned elements without a zIndex?

Comment: jQueryUI wants you to set the z-index on the ui-front css class. There is more information here. http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/stacking-elements/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply the zIndex using jQuery as soon as you instantiate the dialog, you can do the following:

```
$('#element').dialog({ your options... }).parent('.ui-dialog').css('zIndex',9999);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the "appendTo" option? Just dynamically add a wrapper with a z-index of what you need it to be, then use the id of that element as the selector in the "appendTo" argument.

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "moveToTop" );
```

reference: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-moveToTop

Answer (score -2):

```
 $('#element').dialog({     modal: true,
                            stack: false,
                            zIndex: 9999,
...
```

worked for me

Comment: If it worked for you'd been using jQuery UI version less then 1.10.

Comment: Yes, zIndex was deprecated in ver 1.10